# applying to number and order by for a column of varchar type in hibernate using criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I am using hibernate. i have below native sql query.

```
select * from some_table order by to_number(someId);
```

here someId column contains all numbers but datatype is of varchar type. so while pulling i need to apply order by. if order by is applied with out to_number then ASCII comparison is done. to avoid that i need to apply order by with to_number.

how can i achieve the same using criteria? i am not using annotations. using hbms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done with Criteria API, because it does not provide conversion from string to number (of for example from varchar to integer in the end).

You can:

- Use Hibernate Criteria and [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=970093) workaround.
- Use HQL and cast if your database supports it: [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)